# Minimising a chat screen in an app?

Tags: app, chat

I wonder if you guys have any suggestions for minimising a screen (e.g. Chat screen) in an app. I think this is more desktop approach not mobile.

Any insights or experience you can share would be really appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can observe in Android mobiles, there is no actual minimizing of a App, you either close it or run it in the background. If this is a secondary chat inside a  app, you don't need a minimizing button, you can show the saved session like any pill in the bottom right corner once he clicks on back. And "x" mark to close the session [Of Course with a alert]. Only in desktop You need a minimize button on the top right corner next to the close button.

Answer (score 2):

### Generally, there is back or close in most of the interactions rather than minimize in mobiles. if it is a case such as chat.

you can directly use close and when the user closes the chat there will be a floating button on the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Facebook messenger app is what I thought right away.  "Minimizing" is not really useful because you only minimize if you intend to access another window. So you either use the home button, or the back button (physical or in-app)